# Sorting multiple strings into an element

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, list, sorting

Below is a small extract of a *very* large file.

I'm looking for a way to get each name and value (on the *Name(x)* and *Value(x)* lines)  into an element of a Array or List type with an "=" between the two.

i.e to get each element to look like " 'name' = 'value' ".

```
[Device|EEP_FEATUREKOI_HFS_Max|Kostia]
--------------------------------
Name(1) = partHeader_A01
Value(1) = 0x10
Desc(1) = (Address 0x000) Article No. / P.C.B No Byte 1
Name(2) = partHeader_A02
Value(2) = 0x9
Desc(2) = (Address 0x001) Article No. / P.C.B No Byte 2
Name(3) = partHeader_A03
Value(3) = 0x95
Desc(3) = (Address 0x002) Article No. / P.C.B No Byte 3
Name(4) = partHeader_A04
Value(4) = 0x38
Desc(4) = (Address 0x003) Article No. / P.C.B No Byte 4
----------------------------------
Name(12) = AdrIctPcbTestDate_Day
Value(12) = 0xFF
Desc(12) = (Address 0x00B) Test Date : Day
---------------------------------
Name(13) = AdrIctPcbTestDate_Month
Value(13) = 0xFF
Desc(13) = (Address 0x00C) Test Date : Month
---------------------------------
Name(14) = AdrIctPcbTestTime_Hour
Value(14) = 0xFF
Desc(14) = (Address 0x00D) Test Time : Hour
---------------------------------
Name(15) = AdrIctPcbTesTime_Minute
Value(15) = 0xFF
Desc(15) = (Address 0x00E) Test Time : Minute
```

So far I can get the names and values. My problem is, when a section has more than 1 byte(denoted with a "_" in the name) I need to place all the byte values in the same element with only one name.

I can't figure out the proper algorithm to get this to work right.

i.e, for **partHeaderArtLK_A01** up to **partHeaderArtLK_A04**, instead of having

**partHeaderArtLK_A01 = 10**

**partHeaderArtLK_A02 = 09**

**partHeaderArtLK_A03 = 95**

**partHeaderArtLK_A04 = 38**

The element would should to look like

**partHeaderArtLK = 10 09 95 38**.

(Note: I inserted the dashed line seperators to make things clearer. They don't (and cannot) exist in the actual file.)

Here's my attempt so far:

```
if (line.contains("Name")&& line.contains("_")) {
   String basicName = line;
   cutName = basicName.split("=")[1].trim();//get substring after '='
   cutName = cutName.substring(0,cutName.lastIndexOf("_"));//removes '_'?

   importantName.add(i, (cutName + " = "));//add to element i
   System.out.println("Line reads: " + basicName);
   System.out.println("Part: " + cutName);

   do{                   
    if (line.contains("Value")) {
      Hex = line.split("=")[1].trim();//get substring after '='
      importantNumber.add(i, Hex);//get substring after '='
      System.out.println("Value: " + Hex);                        
    }//end if                  
  }while(!"Value".contains(line = reader.readLine()));
   while (!placeToFinish[i].equals(line = reader.readLine()));

 }else    
   if(line.contains("Name")) {
     String basicName = line;
     cutName = basicName.split("=")[1].trim();//get substring after '='

     importantName.add(i, (cutName + " = "));//get substring after '='
     System.out.println("Line reads: " + basicName);
     System.out.println("Part: " + cutName);
     System.out.println("Number: " + importantNumber.indexOf(i) + "\n"); 

    do{  
      if (line.contains("Value")) {
       Hex = line.split("=")[1].trim();//get substring after '='
       importantNumber.add(i, Hex);//get substring after '='
     }//end if                    
   }while (!"Value".contains(line = reader.readLine()));
    while (!placeToFinish[i].equals(line = reader.readLine()));
 }//end if
```

Here's the link to the full code: http://justpaste.it/d3u0
All algorithms or code is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's too much code dude!!.Please post essential part.

Comment: Ok, will do. I'll post a link to the full code for anyone who needs it.

Comment: @user2798632 Have you considered using a simple state machine? That might work. Another approach would be to finalize the prior value only after you confirm that the next name isn't a continuation of the prior one.

Comment: @Eric Stein I've never used state machines and don't know anything about them. I've also thought about the approach you mentioned but I'm still tring to figure out how to do that :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are doing it is a little bit complicated (sorry I didn't even read the hole code).

From the output you are wanting to have, this is how I would do it:

I would use a `Map` which has as key the name without the the part after the underscore and as value a `List` of values.

I.e.:

When you read a line starting with `Name` extract that name from the line and remove the part after the the underscore (including). Save that name in variable whitch remains persistent through the loops.

When you read a line starting with `Value` extract the value again and look up the corresponding `List` from the `Map` using the name you have saved before. If the `List` does not exist, then create one and put it into the `Map`. Then add the value into the `List`.

Here is how it looks like:

```
private Map<String, List<String>> readValues(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    Map<String, List<String>> nameToValuesMap  = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    String line = null;
    String actName = null; 
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.startsWith("Name")) {
            String[] split = line.split("\\s*=\\s*", 2);
            String name = split[1];
            int i = name.indexOf('_');
            if(i != -1) {
                name = name.substring(0, i);
            }
            actName = name;
        } else if(line.startsWith("Value")) {
            String[] split = line.split("\\s*=\\s*", 2);
            String value = split[1].replace("0x", "");
            if(actName != null) {
                List<String> values = nameToValuesMap.get(actName);
                if(values == null) {
                    values = new ArrayList<String>();
                    nameToValuesMap.put(actName, values);
                }
                values.add(value);
            }
        }
    }

    return nameToValuesMap;
}
```

And for some testing I used the sample text you have posted:

```
@Test
public void readpartValues() throws IOException {
    String fielData = "[Device|EEP_FEATUREKOI_HFS_Max|Kostia]\r\n" + 
            "--------------------------------\r\n" + 
            "Name(1) = partHeader_A01\r\n" + 
            "Value(1) = 0x10\r\n" + 
            "Desc(1) = (Address 0x000) Article No. / P.C.B No Byte 1\r\n" + 
            "Name(2) = partHeader_A02\r\n" + 
            "Value(2) = 0x9\r\n" + 
            "Desc(2) = (Address 0x001) Article No. / P.C.B No Byte 2\r\n" + 
            "Name(3) = partHeader_A03\r\n" + 
            "Value(3) = 0x95\r\n" + 
            "Desc(3) = (Address 0x002) Article No. / P.C.B No Byte 3\r\n" + 
            "Name(4) = partHeader_A04\r\n" + 
            "Value(4) = 0x38\r\n" + 
            "Desc(4) = (Address 0x003) Article No. / P.C.B No Byte 4\r\n" + 
            "----------------------------------\r\n" + 
            "Name(12) = AdrIctPcbTestDate_Day\r\n" + 
            "Value(12) = 0xFF\r\n" + 
            "Desc(12) = (Address 0x00B) Test Date : Day\r\n" + 
            "---------------------------------\r\n" + 
            "Name(13) = AdrIctPcbTestDate_Month\r\n" + 
            "Value(13) = 0xFF\r\n" + 
            "Desc(13) = (Address 0x00C) Test Date : Month\r\n" + 
            "---------------------------------\r\n" + 
            "Name(14) = AdrIctPcbTestTime_Hour\r\n" + 
            "Value(14) = 0xFF\r\n" + 
            "Desc(14) = (Address 0x00D) Test Time : Hour\r\n" + 
            "---------------------------------\r\n" + 
            "Name(15) = AdrIctPcbTesTime_Minute\r\n" + 
            "Value(15) = 0xFF\r\n" + 
            "Desc(15) = (Address 0x00E) Test Time : Minute";


    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(fielData.getBytes())));

    Map<String, List<String>> nameToValuesMap  = readValues(reader);
    reader.close();

    List<String> partHeaderValues = nameToValuesMap.get("partHeader");
    System.out.println("partHeader = " + partHeaderValues.toString());

    List<String> adrIctPcbTestTimeValues = nameToValuesMap.get("AdrIctPcbTestTime");
    System.out.println("AdrIctPcbTestTime = " + adrIctPcbTestTimeValues.toString());
}
```

**Output**

```
partHeader = [10, 9, 95, 38]
AdrIctPcbTestTime = [FF]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @EricStein, I dont thik this looks like home work, and less the answer  is worth downvoting, and whoever did, he should at least leave a constructive comment.

Comment: Totally agree. I upvoted just to balance out the undeserved downvote.

Comment: @Eric Stein this is **not** _homework_. My boss has given me the task of doing some coding (of which I know a little Java) and I've run into this problem.

Comment: @A4L I think I can change this around. Is there any way to remove the brackets? I would upvote answer but not enough Rep(15).

Comment: @user2798632 the brackest come only from the List#toString(), the elements inside the list are all ok, just iterate over the list and get the values! -> `for(String valueWithoutBrackets : list) { ... }`

Comment: @user2798632 And that work is happening in package javaproject2? I'm afraid I'm not buying it.

Comment: @AL4 Thanks for all of this. Soon as I can I'll upvote the answer too!

Comment: @Eric Stein this is the _second_ project I've been asked to make for my boss! tbh say what you like, it's 15:12 on a Friday right now so I'm almost finished _work_ for today. I'm passed caring.

Comment: @Eric Stein the fact you think this could be my _second **ever** java project_ is just silly! I'd be chuffed if I got this far if it was.

Answer (score 1):

Base idea - to create output map like "name -> (list of values)". Thereafter - print it.
But I not sure, is java suitable instrument for solve this task. See my program on PERL, which does this job:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

my %nv;
while(<>) {
  my ($nm, $ndx, $val) = m/^(\w+)?\((\d+)\)\s*=\s*(\w+)/;
  next unless $val;
  $nv{$ndx}{$nm} = $val;
}

my %out;
foreach my $k(sort keys %nv) {
  my $name = $nv{$k}{"Name"};
  $name =~ s/_.+//;
  push(@{$out{$name}}, map {s/^0x//; $_ } $nv{$k}{"Value"});
}

while(my ($nm, $vlist) = each %out) {
  print "$nm = " . join(" ", @{$vlist}) . "\n";
}
```

Output for your sample:

```
$ ./nv.pl nv.txt
AdrIctPcbTesTime = FF
AdrIctPcbTestDate = FF FF
partHeader = 10 9 95 38
AdrIctPcbTestTime = FF
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The output is _almost_ right but I don't know PERL and this is just part of a bigger program already written in Java.

Comment: I edited program, and this version removes "0x" at begin of each value, if exist. Also, it links pairs "Name=Value" by index, not by line number..

Comment: Haha thanks again. It'll come in handy for those who know PERL anyway.